# Find the order of the following?

Tags: group-theory

I have attempted (answers of the order that i attempted are in the image) the following by finding the order of each element i.e. order of the element 11 in ℤ20 and the element 7 in ℤ24 and i found |11|=2 and |7|=2 is this right? and then i used the formula

The order of a direct product G × H is the product of the orders of G and H:
| G × H | = | G | | H |.

and then

The order of each element (g, h) is the least common multiple of the orders of g and h:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzp1C.png)
| (g, h) | = lcm(| g |, | h |).

am I even on the right track or is it completely wrong?

[image: Find the order of each of the following elements in the respective groups:]

Comment: Start by identifying the orders of the component parts - for example the order of $11$ in $\mathbb Z_{20}$. Can the order of the combined element be less than this? How do you combine the orders of elements - if you don't know, try thinking about the first one and see what you can work out.

Comment: I think you may be thinking $11^2=121\equiv 1\bmod 20$, but the group operation for $\mathbb Z_{20}$ is addition, not multiplication. It looks as though $U(24)$ is the multiplicative group of integers prime to $24$, for which multiplication is the relevant operation.

Answer (score 0):

Listen the order of 11 in $\mathbb Z_{20} $ is not $2$ if you consider it as a group under the operation of addition modulo $20$.

In fact,the element $11$ is the generator of the group $\mathbb Z_{20} $.

$11^2(mod 20)$ $\equiv$ $22(mod 20)$ $\equiv$ $2(mod 20)$

I.e. we are taking the operation of addition modulo $20$ not multiplication modulo $20$.
And then $11^6(mod 20)$ $\equiv$ $2^3(mod 20)$  $\equiv$ $6(mod 20)$
And so on....
 And we will get that $11^{20}(mod 20)$ $\equiv$ $2^{10}(mod 20)$  $\equiv$ $20(mod 20)$  $\equiv$ $0(mod 20)$

or the order of the element $11$ is $20$ in the group $\mathbb Z_{20} $.

Similar arguments for the element $7$.

Comment: may i ask how 11^2 (mod20) ≡ 22(mod20) ≡ 2(mod20)

Comment: Group operation is addition modulo $20$. I.e.$11^2$ $\equiv$ $11+11$

Answer (score 0):

The *group* $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ is the *additive* group of integers modulo 20.  Then we find the order of 11 in the integers modulo $20$ by repeated addition:\begin{align*}
11 \cong 11  \\
+11 &\cong 22 \cong 2  \\
+11 &\cong 13  \\
+11 &\cong 24 \cong 4  \\
+11 &\cong 15  &[5 \times 11]  \\
+11 &\cong 26 \cong 6  \\
+11 &\cong 17  \\
+11 &\cong 28 \cong 8  \\
+11 &\cong 19  \\
+11 &\cong 30 \cong 10 &[10 \times 11]  \\
+11 &\cong 21 \cong 1  \\
+11 &\cong 12  \\
+11 &\cong 23 \cong 3  \\
+11 &\cong 14  \\
+11 &\cong 25 \cong 5  &[15 \times 11]  \\
+11 &\cong 16  \\
+11 &\cong 27 \cong 7  \\
+11 &\cong 18  \\
+11 &\cong 29 \cong 9  \\
+11 &\cong 20 \cong 0  &\text{stop, $0$ is the identity}  && [20 \times 11]
\end{align*}
Or we could magnificently simplify this by noting that $\gcd(11,20) = 1$, so the multiples of $11$ have to generate all the residue classes modulo $20$, so the order of $11$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{20}$ is $20$.